# Native library (linux-x86-64/libtesseract.so) not found in resource path

Tags: java, tesseract, rhel7

I have RHEL7.3 in which i have built tesseract and i am able to execute my jar . Now i have another system with same RHEL configuration and i want to execute the same jar But i don't want to build tesseract on this system so I pick /usr/lib64/libtesseract.so and /usr/lib64/liblept.so from previously builded tesseract system and put these so files in fresh RHEL7.3 system at /usr/lib64/
path and try to execute my jar but this time my jar did not execute succesfully .It ends with throwing '**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'tesseract': Native library (linux-x86-64/libtesseract.so) not found in resource path**' .What did i miss(dependencies)

I have
 - RHEL 7.3 (64 bit)
 - JRE 1.8.0_51 (64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
yum install tesseract-ocr
```